# Is there any Flutter SDK 32 bit support?

Tags: flutter

From flutter website I came across system requirements and it's actually supporting only 64 bit architectures.

Is there any way to use a 32 bit windows and VS Code or should I wait for any eventual upcoming 32 bit support?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it mentioned in flutter's GitHub issues:

> Support for 32-bit Windows isn't currently planned. If our assumptions are incorrect and there's a very significant demand, we might re-evaluate that decision.

You can follow it up [from here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14925)

Comment: i saw that i tought since february there would be some way or some support that i did not know.. it's sad !